# Translating Windows Forms Drawing Logic to Xamarin.Forms with SkiaSharp

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms, gdi

I have a Windows Forms application with the following drawing logic using Graphics and PictureBox:

I'm currently porting this application to Xamarin.Forms and using SkiaSharp for drawing. My UI structure includes an Image inside a StackLayout. I'm seeking assistance in translating the existing drawing logic to work with Xamarin.Forms and SkiaSharp.

```
        private void pictureboxpaint()
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            using (Graphics gfx = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
            {
                try
                {
                    gfx.ScaleTransform(piczoom, piczoom);
                }
                catch { }
                gfx.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.NearestNeighbor;
                ColorMatrix matrix = new ColorMatrix();
                ImageAttributes attributes = new ImageAttributes();
                foreach (Control c in flowLayoutPanel1.Controls)
                {
                    if (((Label)c.Controls[0]).Text == "   ")
                    {
                        string[] ll3 = ((PictureBox)c.Controls[1]).Name.Contains(".") ? ((PictureBox)c.Controls[1]).Name.Split('.') : ((PictureBox)c.Controls[1]).Name.Split(',');
                        matrix.Matrix33 = (float)int.Parse(ll3[6]) / 100;
                        attributes.SetColorMatrix(matrix, ColorMatrixFlag.Default, ColorAdjustType.Bitmap);
                        gfx.DrawImage(((PictureBox)c.Controls[1]).Image, new Rectangle(int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]), int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[12])), int.Parse(ll3[2]), int.Parse(ll3[3]), int.Parse(ll3[4]), int.Parse(ll3[5]), GraphicsUnit.Pixel, attributes);
                        if (ll3[13] != "0")
                        {
                            SolidBrush solidBrush;
                            if (ll3[13] == "1")
                            {
                                solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
                                gfx.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.SkyBlue, 5), int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]), int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[12]));
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                gfx.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Red, 5), int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]), int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[12]));
                                solidBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Blue);
                            }
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]) + int.Parse(ll3[12]) / 2, 10, 10);
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]), 10, 10);
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]) + int.Parse(ll3[11]) / 2, int.Parse(ll3[1]) + int.Parse(ll3[12]), 10, 10);
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]) + int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[1]), 10, 10);
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]), int.Parse(ll3[1]) + int.Parse(ll3[12]), 10, 10);
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]) + int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[1]) + int.Parse(ll3[12]), 10, 10);
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]) + int.Parse(ll3[11]), int.Parse(ll3[1]) + int.Parse(ll3[12]) / 2, 10, 10);
                            gfx.FillEllipse(solidBrush, int.Parse(ll3[0]) + int.Parse(ll3[11]) / 2, int.Parse(ll3[1]), 10, 10);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            drawmarkers();
        }
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="BeautyFly.MainPage"
             BackgroundColor="#404040">

    <StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Button Text="File" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Settings" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                    <Button Text="Filters" BackgroundColor="Transparent" TextColor="White" Clicked="Button_Clicked" TextTransform="None"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ScrollView x:Name="scrol" Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10,0">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <ImageButton ClassId="BIE Default startup image@0,0,0,0,640,640,100,0,0,640,640,640,640,0@@@0@1@0" Source="a" HeightRequest="60" WidthRequest="60" Aspect="AspectFit" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <!-- Add more elements as needed -->
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="picturebox2" Aspect="AspectFit" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout>
            <Image x:Name="picturebox" Source="a" Aspect="AspectFit" />
        </StackLayout>
        <ListView x:Name="menuListView" ItemSelected="menuListView_ItemSelected" IsVisible="false">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>add</x:String>
                    <x:String>open</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
        <ListView x:Name="menuListView1" ItemSelected="menuListView1_ItemSelected" IsVisible="false">
            <ListView.ItemsSource>
                <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                    <x:String>Select</x:String>
                    <x:String>Hide</x:String>
                    <x:String>Editor</x:String>
                    <x:String>Remove</x:String>
                    <x:String>Lock</x:String>
                </x:Array>
            </ListView.ItemsSource>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```